# Calculate the run length of a variable and plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to plot an ordered sequence of numbers that is colored by a factor. For example, given this fake data:

```
# Generate fake data
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)
plot.data <- data.frame(fitted = rnorm(20),
                        actual = sample(0:1, 20, replace=TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(fitted)

head(plot.data)
      fitted actual
1 -1.8179560      0
2 -0.9193220      1
3 -0.8863575      1
4 -0.7505320      1
5 -0.4534972      1
6 -0.3315776      0
```

I can easily plot the `actual` column from rows 1–20 as colored lines:

```
# Plot with lines
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=seq(length.out = length(actual)), colour=factor(actual))) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=0, ymax=1))
```

[image: Plot with linerange]

The gist of this plot is to show how often the `actual` numbers appear sequentially across the range of `fitted` values. As you can see in the image, sequential 0s and 1s are readily seen as sequential blue and red vertical lines.

However, I'd like to move away from the lines and use `geom_rect` instead to create bands for the sequential number. I can fake this with really thick lineranges:

```
# Fake rectangular regions with thick lines
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=seq(length.out = length(actual)), colour=factor(actual))) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=0, ymax=1), size=10)
```

[image: Plot with thick lines that are fake rectangles]

But the size of these lines is dependent on the number of observations—if they're too thick, they'll overlap. Additionally, doing this means that there are a bunch of extraneous graphical elements that are plotted (i.e. sequential rectangular sections are really just a bunch of line segments that bleed into each other). It would be better to use `geom_rect` instead.

However, `geom_rect` requires that data include minimum and maximum values for x, meaning that I need to reshape `actual` to look something like this instead:

```
xmin xmax colour
   0    1    red
   1    5   blue
```

I need to programmatically calculate the run length of each color to mark the beginning and end of that color. I know that R has the `rle()` function, which is likely the best option for calculating the run length, but I'm unsure about how to split the run length into two columns (`xmin` and `xmax`).

What's the best way to calculate the run length of a variable so that `geom_rect` can plot it correctly?

Comment: cumsum(plot.data$actual) could give you a useful variable to use as group aesthetic for geom_rect

Comment: Yes, though it ends up creating 9 levels—I'd need to collapse those levels into just two (even and odd groups). *EDIT:* Rather, I'd need to use it to determine when the cumsum doesn't increase. Still tricky.

Comment: `geom_rect(aes(xmin=seq(length.out = length(actual)),xmax=seq(length.out = length(actual))+1,ymin=0,ymax=1, group=cumsum(actual),fill=factor(actual)))`

Comment: It works without `group=cumsum(actual)` too. However, it's still plotting each `geom_rect` individually. For example, adding a white border shows this: http://imgur.com/0RaOIyA Is there a way to end up with just 8 rectangles instead of 20? Ultimately, my real data has thousands of observations and the plot gets bogged down with so many geoms…

Comment: I see. You need to process the data beforehand, something like `d %>% mutate(x = seq_along(actual), change = c(0, diff(actual))) %>% subset(change != 0 )` would be a good start. Needs some reshaping, before being passed as data to the geom_rect layer.

Comment: Ah. The trick is the `c(0, diff(actual))` column. All that's left is adding the first row back at the top of the condensed data frame and leading the x variable to get xmax.

Comment: I just added an update above with this method. Do you want to stick your comment as an answer so we can close this up?

Comment: feel free to post and accept your own answer, I don't mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @baptiste, it seems that the best way to go about this is to condense the data into just those rows that see a change in x:

```
condensed <- plot.data %>% 
  mutate(x = seq_along(actual), change = c(0, diff(actual))) %>% 
  subset(change != 0 ) %>% select(-change)

first.row <- plot.data[1,] %>% mutate(x = 0)

condensed.plot.data <- rbind(first.row, condensed) %>%
  mutate(xmax = lead(x),
         xmax = ifelse(is.na(xmax), max(x) + 1, xmax)) %>%
  rename(xmin = x)

condensed.plot.data
#       fitted actual xmin xmax
# 1 -1.8179560      0    0    2
# 2 -0.9193220      1    2    6
# 3 -0.3315776      0    6    9
# 4 -0.1162478      1    9   11
# 5  0.2987237      0   11   14
# 6  0.5855288      1   14   15
# 7  0.6058875      0   15   20
# 8  1.8173120      1   20   21

ggplot(condensed.plot.data) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=0, ymax=1, fill=factor(actual)))
```

[image: Plot with actual rectangles]